# Activity exit animation not working

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I have transparent activity(Activity2) on top of Activity1. I want to move Activity1 to left when showing Activity2.
I am using `overridePendingTransition` when starting Activity2 it works fine if I finish Activity1 and exit animation is shown. If I don't finish Activity1 exit animation don't work.

So my question is that how can I move Activity1 to left without finishing it.

Comment: Maybe using fragment instead of activity could provide better control for you

Comment: Yes but I have different activities.

Comment: Did you tried without handler and add your answer in edit.

Comment: I want to hide it after delay thats why I am using handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have achieved hiding my activity

```
protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        final View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }, 400);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        getWindow().getDecorView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: Edit this in your question